# How to create a counter in google sheets that would count how many times a calculated cell has changed value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner and need to write a script that will count the number of times that a cell, the value in which is formula-calculated (no user input) changed value over a day and then at midnight reset the count back to 0

I have tried to use the onEdit code, but it only works with user input changes and doesn't take into account when a formula changes the value of a cell, based on other values

Here is a link to a sample spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QfM764_cPbtN46oDSbGBFgVNYZ1R6dwxIs744cyRsS4/edit?usp=sharing

The column H has the Signal (Buy or Sell) which is calculated based on the prices and can change throughout the day. 
The code should put the number of times the signal was on Buy or Sell throughout the day, and then reset at days end.

Any help would be really appreciated since I am very stuck on this.

**EDIT**

I have come up with this code, which works on one row of data:

```
function Counter(e) {  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Counter");
  var r = s.getRange("H2");
  var v= r.getValue();
  var h = s.getRange("N2").getValue();
    if(v !== h) {
      var sCounter = s.getRange("I2");
      var timestamprange = s.getRange("J2")
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

      var counter = sCounter.getValue();

      if(counter === 0) {
          counter = 1;
          } else {
            counter ++;
          }
          sCounter.setValue(counter);
          timestamprange.setValue(formattedDate)
      ;}
 s.getRange(2, 14).setValue(v)
}
```

How can I adjust the code to make the same for the ranges "H2:H51", "I2:I51", "J2:J51" ?

**EDIT 2:**

I tried on my own and came up with this code, which doesn´t work:

```
function Test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Counter");
  var newvalues = s.getRange("H2:H51").getValues();
  var oldvalues = s.getRange("N2:N51").getValues();

  for(n=0;n<newvalues.length;++n){
    var nv = newvalues[n][0] ; 
    var o = oldvalues[n][0] ;
    if(nv !== o) {
      var sCounter = s.getRange("I2:I51");
      var timestamprange = s.getRange("J2:J51");
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      var counter = sCounter.getValues();
      if(counter[n][0] === 0) {
        counter[n][0] = 1;
        } else {
            counter[n][0] ++;
          }
      sCounter.setValues(counter[n][0]);
      timestamprange.setValue(formattedDate);
    }

}
  s.getRange("N2:N51").setValues(newvalues)
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of the cell based on? If those cells are the same/controlled, then you can use onEdit to track those cells as well? a running total should represent the total changes.

Comment: The value of the sell is based on price difference. Here is the formula from column H to be exact - =if(E2>B2,"Buy",if(E2<B2,"Sell","")). I have tried onEdit but didnt get it to work, as I have understood it takes into account (triggers) only on user inflicted change

Comment: you will need a script for that

Comment: Yes, that why I am here :)

Comment: Tell us more about your scenario. How many rows of data are there in Col H? How long does the spreadsheet take to recalculate? Using a simple counter, how long does it take to process through every row of your live data? What is the absolute minimum time-check frequency that you can accept? Answers to these questions would be important if, perhaps, a  time-driven event (trigger) were to be used. Though you would have to juggle the execution frequency with the aggregate execution time.

Comment: Update: I have come up with a code, which does the work for one row of data. The trigger is set to every minute, which is ok. However now my problem is to adapt this code for all the 50 rows, really have no clue how to do it. I know I must use arrays and compare them, but can´t come up with the correct loops. Sample data can be seen in the spreadsheet, the link is attached in the my initial question. Thanks again for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an answer that works for me, I am sure that it is not optimal, but it gets the job done) Have set a trigger to run every minute. It also adds the date and time in the next column, if the counter changes value, to track the last change, if anybody should need it.
Upgrades to the code are more than welcome

The working code:

```
function Counter() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("DataStructured");
  var newvalues = s.getRange("H2:H51").getValues();
  var oldvalues = s.getRange("N2:N51").getValues();

  for(n=0;n<newvalues.length;++n){
    var nv = newvalues[n][0]; 
    var o = oldvalues[n][0];
    if(nv !== o) {
      var sCounter = s.getRange("I2:I51");
      var timestamprange = s.getRange("J2:J51")
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

      var counter = sCounter.getValues();
      if(counter[n][0] === 0) {
        counter[n][0] = 1;
        } else {
            counter[n][0] ++;
          }
      sCounter.setValues(counter);
      s.getRange("J"+(n+2)).setValue(formattedDate);
    }

}
  s.getRange("N2:N51").setValues(newvalues)
}
```